# Confirmation URL for Shopify RecurringApplicationCharge is nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, recurring-billing, shopify-api

Im trying to add a recurring charge to my shopify app. I followed the [Shopify-Tutorial](https://shopify.dev/tutorials/add-billing-to-your-app) but wrote it slightly different. My root route goes to:

```
root 'mycontroller#charging'
```

the controller action is:

```
  def charging
    if @shop_domain != @myshop
      @shop_charging_status = @shop.charging
      unless ShopifyAPI::RecurringApplicationCharge.current
        recurring_charge = ShopifyAPI::RecurringApplicationCharge.new(
          name: "My App",
          price: "1.99",
          return_url: "https:\/\/appurl\/activated",
          trial_days: 7,
          terms: "$1.99 per month")

          if recurring_charge.save
            @tokens[:confirmation_url] = recurring_charge.confirmation_url
            @shop_charging_status = true
            @shop.save
            redirect recurring_charge.confirmation_url
          end
      end
    else
      redirect_to myindex_path
    end
```

When I try to start the app, i get an error: NoMethodError (undefined method `[]=' for nil:NilClass). It concerns the @token line. This line already confused me when i wrote the code, because the variable @token is only used in this method. But nevertheless, why is it nil?

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When I try to start the app, i get an error: NoMethodError (undefined method `[]=' for nil:NilClass). It concerns the @token line.

I assume you mean `@tokens`?

I think you're missing the first part of [the tutorial here](https://shopify.dev/tutorials/build-a-shopify-app-with-ruby-and-sinatra) in which they set `@tokens = {}` in the initialize method and then store the access tokens for each shop in there.

Comment: You are right. I have the shopify-app gem, so its not necessary. I fixed it by simply deleting [:confirmation_url] and put a fullpage_redirect_to @token. Now it works